# how to use math.random() with a range of specific numbers?

Tags: java

### I'm trying to use math.random() to create a dice which is 4 sided, and each of its sides is labeled with a unique number: 2, 3, 5 or 7 and then print it. For example i want it to print:

7 7 5 2 (each number is random of the range (2,3,5 or 7)

i am a beginner and only learned up till loops and about library classes (NOT ARRAYS or PROGRAMMER DEFINED METHODS and onward)

what I've tried is below but is obviously wrong: PLEASE HELP ! THANKS !

```
    int d1 = (int)(Math.random() * 4) + 1;
    int d2 = (int)(Math.random() * 4) + 1;
    int d3 = (int)(Math.random() * 4) + 1;
    int d4 = (int)(Math.random() * 4) + 1;

    for (int i=1; i<=4; i++)
    {
        if (d1 == 1 || d2 == 1 || d3 == 1 || d4 == 1)
        {
            d1=2;
            d2=2;
            d3=2;
            d4=2;
        }
        else if (d1 == 2 || d2 == 2 || d3 == 2 || d4 == 2)
        {
            d1=3;
            d2=3;
            d3=3;
            d4=3;
        }
        else if (d1 == 3 || d2 == 3 || d3 == 3 || d4 == 3)
        {
            d1=5;
            d2=5;
            d3=5;
            d4=5;
        }
        else if (d1 == 4 || d2 == 4 || d3 == 4 || d4 == 4)
        {
            d1=7;
            d2=7;
            d3=7;
            d4=7;
        }
        i++;
    }
    System.out.println(d1 + " " + d2 + " " + d3 + " " + d4);
```

Comment: I do not understand what your loop is for.  It does the same unchanging code.

Comment: why are you processing and changing all 4 values at once, why set them to the same value?

Comment: You want an array, with 4 entries.  So it might be `int[] dice = { 2, 3, 5, 7 };`.  Then to get a random value, you might do something like `dice[random.nextInt(4)]`, where `random` is an instance of `Random`.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem solution is a lot nicer. see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem you understand my issue and your answer would be correct. but i have not learned arrays yet. is there a way to get those specific numbers randomly using math.random() or even the random class? maybe with loops? i know my code is incorrect. thanks!

Comment: Then today would be an excellent day to learn about arrays.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem  (w/o arrays) Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

String diceNum = "2357";

int playerDice1 = diceNum.charAt((int) (Math.random() * 4)) - '0';

System.out.println(playerDice1);